# Why isn't this alert displayed on first click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a button. When I click the button, I want it to run a PHP file and display alert. Here's what I'm trying:
HTML:

```
<button id="testid" style="height:20px; width: 50px; cursor: pointer" onclick="logoutfunc()">Logout</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function logoutfunc() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#testid").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'logoutt.php',
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result11) {
                    //$(location).attr('href', 'login.php');
                    alert(result11);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("no");
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**logoutt.php**

```
<?php
$a="Hello";
echo $a;
?>
```

Now the problem is that when I click the button first time, it doesn't display the alert. But when I click it again, it displays same alert twice. And when I click it again, it alerts 3 times and so on. What wrong have I written?

Answer (score 4):

You are binding the click handler inside the inline event handler, thus when the button is clicked first time the event handler is attached. So it works second time.

Get rid of the inline click handler. just bind the event handler using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testid").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'logoutt.php',
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result11) {
                //$(location).attr('href', 'login.php');
                alert(result11);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("no");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you again and again binding the same event?

```
....onclick="logoutfunc()"...
```

Remove this part from your *HTML* and in your javascript remove the function which surrounds the *document ready* handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#testid").click(function(){
     // your ajax code.
  });      
});
```